# Python library for dot product classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

I have the following python pyseudo-code:

```
A1 = "101000001111"
A2 = "110000010101"
B2 = "000111010000"
B2 = "000110100000"
# TODO get X = [x1, x2, ..., x12]
assert(A1 * X > .5)
assert(A2 * X > .5)
assert(B1 * X < .5)
assert(B2 * X < .5)
```

So this will basically be a regression based classification.

0.5 is my threshold but how to get X?

Comment: Sorry but your question makes no sense, what is even regression based classification?

Comment: There are classifiers that are based on regression:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html .

Comment: I simply need these coefficients.

Comment: I could get the coefficients like this: LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(X, y).coef_ ok but how can I use them to calculate something like A1 * X > .5 ?

Comment: LogisticRegression is a classifier, it is not "based on regression", the name is very unfortunate and it gives these confusions.

Comment: You could just look at sklearn's source code, numpy also has many functions to compute dot products: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/36958fb240fbe435673a9e3c52e769f01f36bec0/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py#L430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to find 12 coefficients. You can try to use `LogisticRegression` or `LinearRegression`
2. When you have linear coefficients you can use `np.dot` or `@` operator to get a dot product.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

A1 = "101000001111"
A2 = "110000010101"
B1 = "000111010000"
B2 = "000110100000"

A1 = np.array(list(A1), np.float32)
A2 = np.array(list(A2), np.float32)
B1 = np.array(list(B1), np.float32)
B2 = np.array(list(B2), np.float32)

X = np.array((A1, A2, B1, B2))
y = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0])
w = model = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X, y).coef_.flatten()

print(A1.dot(w))
print(A2.dot(w))
print(B1.dot(w))
print(B2.dot(w))

assert A1 @ w > 0.5
assert A2 @ w > 0.5
assert B1 @ w < 0.5
assert B2 @ w < 0.5
```

Results:

```
1.7993630995882384
1.5032155788245702
-1.0190643734998346
-1.0385501901808816
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is awesome. I can now go ahead and implement this. All the Best!